# Can all skills be unlocked through skill packs?

Tags: guild-wars

There are five "skill unlock packs" available in the Guild Wars store: Core, Prophecies, Factions, Nightfall and EotN.

These are all described as unlocking X number of skills, elite and non-elite, but they don't specify if they unlock *all* skills for a given campaign.

If I were to buy all skill packs, would they unlock all the skills available in Guild Wars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This partially depends on whether you mean for a PvP or PvE character.

For a PvP character, yes, the purchasing all skill packs will allow you complete use of all campaign skills in PvP.

For a PvE character, no, as [PvE-only skills](http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/List_of_PvE-only_skills), cannot be unlocked via skill pack purchases. So, for example, you'd still have to do quests for the various factions in Eye of the North to get those skills.

Note that for PvE characters, this doesn't mean that you automatically will have all these skills learned on your character. You will still have to pay to learn non-elites and capture elites. However,  non-elites *will* be available on all skill trainers for you, which can be especially valuable in the early game, where the skill trainer's offerings are more limited. You can also learn unlocked skills through elite/non-elite skill tomes, and, perhaps the handiest feature, all unlocked skills will be available for you to equip on your Heroes.

Comment: You can also buy most of the PvE skills.